# After EnterWriteLock the lock is not held

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I have a AVL tree data structure, where every node has its own lock. Its because there is more writers which are trying to acces a node.

```
class Node
{
    public ReaderWriterLockSlim ww;
    // ...
    public Node()
    {
        ww = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);
        // ...
    }
}
class AVL_tree
{
    public Node root;
    // ...
    public void Write(int value)
    {
        root = new Node();
        root.ww.EnterWriteLock();
        if (!root.ww.IsWriteLockHeld) throw new Exception("Why?");
        // ...
        root.ww.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Each writer is starting in new thread

```
class Program{
    public static AVL_Tree data;
    static void Main()
    {
        data = new AVL_Tree();
        List<Thread> vlakna = new List<Thread>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            vlakna.Add(new Thread(Write));
        foreach (Thread vlakno in vlakna)
            vlakno.Start();
    }
    public static void Write() // Write some random data into the tree
    {
        Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        data.Writer(rnd.Next(1, 999));
    }
```

Writer doesn't look exactly like this, there is more nodes and more of code, but the problem is following:

After locking the node, the lock is not held, **sometimes**. I don't understand why.
Have anyone some kind of explanation.

*Sometimes means that I can't find out when it is going to happend.

Comment: As is obvious when copying and pasting this code into a project, it's not like your real code. There are a number of errors in it that prevent it compiling, and if they're fixed in the obvious way, then no exception is thrown. Please try to create a short but complete, *compilable* example that demonstrates the problem. (You may discover the solution yourself whilst attempting to do this)

Comment: No it was not a real code, now it is code, but still I can't copy here whole project, because its too long. This is just a interpretation of problem.

Comment: You are holding a write lock, not a read lock.  Change the test to ww.IsWriteLockHeld

Comment: I'm talking about WriteLock, just mistake. And yes this code works. But in my whole project it doesn't.

Comment: Again though, if we fix the compile errors in the code you've posted, it *doesn't* exhibit the problem you're describing. It's next to impossible for us to debug code that *we haven't been shown*. Start with an empty project. Then, maybe using the above as a starting point, start adding more of the *actual* code into the project, until such time as it actually *exhibits* the problem. (Then see if you can remove any irrelevant parts whilst making sure it still exhibits the problem)

Comment: It would be worth bearing in mind that despite the name, ReaderWriterLockSlim actually has quite a large memory footprint. On my 32bit XP machine it's about 1KB for a new instance, which after significant use (i.e. entering the lock from many different threads) can increase to about 7KB per instance. As such, having a lock-per-node may not be the best decision if the number of nodes is large.

Comment: I just wanted to find a logical mistake (that I found thanks to Matthew Watson) I knew that it can't be debuged, even I had problems with "working code". Problem occured in 1/50 cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it is being accessed by a different thread? If it is the same thread recursively acquiring the lock, it will be granted to every recursion level.

To see if this is the case, change the lock recursion policy to NoRecursion and see if you get an exception.

[EDIT]

Here's another thought: You have a race condition.

Each thread you start is calling data.Write(), i.e. AVL_tree.Write().

Inside AVL_tree.Write() you assign a new root node.

Let's examine your AVL_tree.Write():

```
class AVL_tree
{
    public Node root;
    // ...
    public void Write(int value)
    {
        root = new Node();         // [A]
        root.ww.EnterWriteLock();  // [B]
        if (!root.ww.IsWriteLockHeld) throw new Exception("Why?"); // [C]
        // ...
        root.ww.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Imagine that thread 1 has executed up to line [B], and is ABOUT TO execute line [C].

Now imagine that thread 2 comes along and executes line [A] and is ABOUT TO execute line [B].

At this point, the root field has been overwritten by a new one, one that has NOT yet acquired its write lock.

Now imagine that thread 1 continues to line [C]. It looks at the root (now the one that was newed by thread 2), and discovers that the write lock is not held and therefore throws an exception.

That is what I think is happening.

Comment: Thanks for new point of view, but I am sure, that this is not the problem. Even after changing recursion policy, the problem remains.

Comment: Thank you very mutch, that was the kind of mistake I made. The repair was following: Copy refernece to root to write method and work with this reference instead of the root.